# What is the rationale behind the naming of the squeeze and unsqueeze operations?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, naming-conventions

I was wondering if there is some (mathematical, historical, etc) reason behind the operations to remove and add singleton dimensions being called `squeeze` and `unsqueeze`. I am mainly asking from a torch perspective but it seems that those names are used also in many other programming languages and libraries.

Especially because you could easily make a case for the naming to be reversed and you would not notice much of a difference. It would make even more sense to me that an operation that removes singleton dimensions would be called `un-squeeze`.

It seems that something more descriptive like `add_singleton_dimension` and `remove_singleton_dimension` would help to better convey the meaning of those operations (like the numpy function `expand_dims` does).

So, is this because the names `squeeze` and `unsqueeze`:

- have been inherited from other programming languages/paradigms
- are defined and used in mathematical language
- retrocompatibility with existing libraries

Comment: numpy doesn't have `unsqueeze`

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for the heads up, i have edited the question to specify pytorch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know `numpy`, not `pytorch`.  But my guess is the `pytorch` borrowed `squeeze` from `numpy`, and invented `unsqueeze` to do the 'reverse'.

`numpy` has lots of ways of adding size 1 dimensions - `arr[:,None,:]`, `reshape`, and `reshape` wrapper `expand_dims`.

With the shape/strides approach to multidimensional arrays, adding and removing size 1 dimensions is a trivial operation.

Talking about 'squeezing out all size 1 dimensions' sounds obvious to me (a native English speaker).  `numpy` where arrays can have 0 or more dimensions is a natural place for this.  MATLAB probably didn't add this function until it allowed more than 2 dimensions.  Even then 2 is the lower boundary.  Specifying which dimensions you want to remove is also a later addition to `numpy`.

Many array operations have physical equivalents.  Squeeze brings to mind squeezing water out a sponge.  Flatten is obvious.  Ravel is another, though English blurs the distinction between that and 'unravel'.  Ultimately those analogies suggest where the name comes from, but shouldn't be used as definitions.